# spring Boot and Angular JS : what is the best way to deal with the authentication?

Tags: angularjs, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-data

I'm devoloping an application using Spring Boot , Spring Data and Angular JS .

**what is the best way to deal  with the authentication ???**

I've never used spring security before and I can't find an example using a database (users and Roles) .can I use spring security even if I have html pages ?

what I want is that when a User (from my database) logs in , he will find his personal data. what I mean is for example like in facebook home page ,the user's name is shown on the topbar , he can see his profil ...

Also a part of my menu must be shown only to my admin user . **is that possible ?**

I'll be gratful if someone can tell me what are the steps to follow or give me a link for a good tutorial . I'm lost

Comment: Have you take a look at JHipster https://jhipster.github.io/?

Comment: When I google "angularjs spring security" I get a load of useful looking links. Did you try that?

Answer (score 1):

You must go through [this](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/) tutorial which was based on [Dave Syer's](https://spring.io/team/dsyer) blog posts. It clearly describes about angularjs with spring boot and authentication.

My personal suggestion for is to use [Spring Security](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security/) with form login, which supports role based authentication. Custom menu display is not that hard when you have angularjs and role based authentication with you. (But I'm afraid you will not be able to have 100% html solution - May have to use jsp if statement.)

Another alternative would be, if you have jboss as application server, you can use [login-config.xml](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-security/jboss-security-framework) to change permissions